# Could not install Ruby 2.0 because Openssl.org down?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I tried to install ruby-2.0.0-p0 on Macintosh at several times. But I never success. I tried `brew install openssl` or `rvm pkg install openssl` but progress bar is always 0% and I never access to [www.openssl.org](http://www.openssl.org). There are no way to install them without openssl. Is this only my probrem? I found any similar resources but there are not help for me... Am I banned from Openssl? Or it is not only my problem? Could you someone tell me any good advice?

**EDIT**

Thanks @fmendez, But I hit same error again... [Full trace on Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5401732)

```
==> Downloading http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
Error: Download failed: http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
$ brew install openssl
==> Downloading http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
                                                                       0.0%
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Error: Download failed: http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
```

**EDIT**

Finally I've connected openssl.org. I didn't know what was the problem :\
Sorry for any attentions. I will delete this.

Answer (score 2):

The url pointed to by the latest `openssl brew formula` is: http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz and it is working fine. Try doing a `brew update`, then the following:

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

**Note**

After running the `rvm requirements` make sure you install any library hinted by `homebrew` if any.